# Define a destroy-method in annotation-based bean?

Tags: spring, annotations, lifecycle

I'm looking for a way to tell spring which method on an annotation-based bean it should call when it's destryoing that bean.

What I'm actually trying to achieve is, to be notified when a session-scoped bean is destroyed in order to persist some stuff from that session.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to implement `DisposableBean`, or (preferably) annotate the method with `javax.annotation.PreDestroy`, which is more portable.

Comment: There's `javax.annotation.PreDestroy` but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: If yo need to register a bean that you don't have control over then you need to wrap it? Or is there a better way to close resources that registered as beans?